# C program to concatenate two pointer strings with functions

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, c-strings, string-concatenation

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
char concaten(const char *str1,const char *str2);
    
int main()
    {
        printf("%s",concaten("Code","blocks"));
        return 0;
    }
    
char concaten(const char *str1,const char *str2) {
    int i=0,j=0;
    char *result;
    while(*str1){
        result[i++]=str1[i++];
    }
    while(*str2){
        result[i+j++]=str2[j++];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I wrote this function to get two strings and add them to another third string; I don't understand where I am going wrong, as it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Your example won't compile for a lot of reasons, let alone output the correct result. Adding to @AdrianMole, you also need to initialize `char *result` and allocate space on the heap for the strings you're concatenating. And your while loops won't ever exit since you're not incrementing the pointer address.

Comment: @dv24680 Most of all I like this loop while(*str1){
            result[i++]=str1[i++];

        } in the function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Use it if you want... once posted on SO it PD

Comment: Where is the memory for `result`

Comment: @4386427 I am not so talented.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Don't give up - keep trying. ;-)

Comment: If you want to concatenate two C-strings into a third, you should either pass the third string and his max length or have the function allocate memory for the result and return the pointer... which needs to be freed later by the caller which is somewhat annoying. By the way, to you know strcat() function and his variants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your `concaten` function.

First, it should be returning a `char*` pointer, not a `char`; thus, the *declaration* should look like this:

```c
char* concaten(const char* str1, const char* str2);
```

Next, the function will need to allocate memory in which to store the concatenated strings; this can be done with the `malloc()` function, and the number of characters required will be the sum of the lengths of the two input strings *plus one*, for the required `nul`-terminator.

Third, the logic of your two loops is wrong. You are incrementing `i` and `j` *twice* per loop but not incrementing either of the *source* pointers.

Finally, you **must** add a `nul`-terminator at the end of your new string.

Here's a version with the above fixes applied:

```c
char* concaten(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char* result = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1); // allow space for nul-terminator
    while (*str1) {
        result[i++] = *str1++; // Only increment i once and "str1" once
    }
    while (*str2) {
        result[i + j++] = *str2++; // Only increment j once and "str2" once
    }
    result[i + j] = '\0'; // Add required nul-terminator
    return result;
}
```

Also, as you have allocated memory (with the `malloc` call), you should release that when you're done with the data, using a call to `free`. Here's how your `main` might work:

```c
int main(void)
{
    char* answer = concaten("Code", "blocks");
    printf("%s", answer);
    free(answer);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: You can also remove the `j` variable entirely, and just re-use the `result[i++]` expression in the second loop. I've left it in so that you can more easily relate my code to your own.

Comment: @4386427 We've all been there buddy :) Hope your day gets better

Comment: What is wrong with `strcpy` and `strcat`?

Comment: I get a little confused when I need to be dereferencing a pointer, for example when returning result, shouldn't we, return *result so the value of the result array gets returned and not the address of the pointer?

Comment: @dv24680 An 'array' is returned from a function as the address of it's first element (i.e. as a pointer).

Answer (score 3):

Your function has the return type char

```
char concaten(const char *str1,const char *str2);
```

but within the function you are returning the variable `result`

```
return result;
```

declared like a pointer of the type `char *`

```
char *result;
```

So the compiler will issue a message that you are trying to convert a pointer to an integer.

The function must be declared like

```
char * concaten(const char *str1,const char *str2);
```

The pointer result is not initialized and has an indeterminate value. You need to allocate memory where you will write concatenated strings.

The while loops in the function will be infinite if `str1` and/or `str2` are not empty strings due to conditions

```
    while(*str1){
```

and

```
    while(*str2){
```

These statements

```
result[i++]=str1[i++];
```

and

```
result[i+j++]=str2[j++];
```

invoke undefined behavior not only because the pointer `result` is not initialized but also because there is no sequence point between left and write operands where there is used the postfix increment operator `++`.

Also the result string must be zero terminated.

If you are not allowed to use standard C string functions then your function can be implemented for example the following way

```
char * concatenate( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    size_t n1 = 0;
    size_t n2 = 0;

    while ( str1[n1] ) ++n1;
    while ( str2[n2] ) ++n2;

    char *result = malloc( n1 + n2 + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
       char *p = result;

       while ( *str1 ) *p++ = *str1++;
       do
       {
           *p++ = *str2;
       } while ( *str2++ );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Also you should not forget to free the allocated memory when the result string is not needed any more.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * concatenate( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    size_t n1 = 0;
    size_t n2 = 0;

    while ( str1[n1] ) ++n1;
    while ( str2[n2] ) ++n2;

    char *result = malloc( n1 + n2 + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
       char *p = result;

       while ( *str1 ) *p++ = *str1++;
       do
       {
           *p++ = *str2;
       } while ( *str2++ );
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *result = concatenate( "Code ", "blocks" );
    
    if ( result != NULL ) puts( result );
    
    free( result );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Code blocks
```

If you may use standard C string functions then the function concatenate can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * concatenate( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( str1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( str2 );

    char *result = malloc( n1 + n2 + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        memcpy( result, str1, n1 );
        memcpy( result + n1, str2, n2 + 1 );
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *result = concatenate( "Code ", "blocks" );
    
    if ( result != NULL ) puts( result );
    
    free( result );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above that is

```
Code blocks
```

Comment: I like it! Not using the `strlen` function (as I did) and checking the return value of `malloc` (as I forgot to do).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that your function should not return `char` but `char*`, the expression `result[i++] = str1[i++];` is not correct it lacks a sequence point. Furthermore `result` is an unitialized pointer, it cannot hold any data, you would need to make it point to some valid memory location.

You could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concatenate(const char* str1, const char* str2 ){

    char* result = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
    if (result){
        char* temp = result;
        while (*str1 != '\0'){
            *temp++ = *str1++;
        }
        while (*str2 != '\0'){
            *temp++ = *str2++;
        }
        *temp = '\0'; // don't forget to null terminate the string      
    }
    return result; // if memory allocation fails a null pointer is returned
}
```

The direct usage of the function in the `printf` statement will not allow you to free the memory and you would have a memory leak if the program didn't finish immediately, in these cases it's best to have the returned pointer assigned as to not lose track of the allocated memory:

```
int main(void){

    char *result = concatenate("Code", "blocks");
    if(result){
        printf("%s", result);
        free(result);
    } 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @4386427 Yeah. Pointing out problems is only *half* an answer (at best). Always better to offer an actual solution (even if it turns out to be unpopular).